# 404 error when trying to install scala with intelij

Tags: scala, intellij-12

I'm trying to install Scala and  set up an intelij 12 project with it, I have installed the Scala plugin successfully and am now trying to make a new project.  When I try to download Scala itself  however, a 404 error appears,  saying that it cant connect to the scala website and to check my proxy settings, anything I could try to resolve the problem.

Comment: This is a bit vague. Are you saying that you have IntelliJ IDEA 12 open, and are using its Plugin Manager to install the Scala plugin? And then, you get the 404 error when -- what? When you click "Browse repositories"? When you select Scala and click "Download and Install"?

Comment: Are you behind a proxied network!?

Comment: Nope, have tried testing the connection and everything seems ok